# Authorizing Android Google Drive API

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

i have implemented Google Drive API in my Android app. But when i am using it with new Account i need to Authorize / i need to open a popup which will show Emails configured in that my mobile and user need to choose in which Email Dive account photos should be uploaded.

But my Necessary is to store all users Photos in one Google Drive. and they should not give any autherizations . It should code wise automatically authorize to my account and start upload photos to my Account. Is it possible. if possible please any one Help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Users can only authorize your app to request their Google Drive on their behalf; hence this `code wise automatically authorize to my account` is not possible at all.

But once they authorize your app, you don't need to show the newAccount pop up every time; you can use the same access token returned during authorization to upload photos to the drive for the selected account.

Comment: Thanks nightlytrails, but i don't want to store Images at User's Drive Account. I want to save all the images in One Account... so i need to Authorize code wise myaccount@gmail.com and store all user's images in same Drive